# Detect when Touch ID is being touched, no authentication

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, touch-id

I'm wondering if it's possible to detect when a user's finger is touching the home button on the iPhone 5S/6, without necessarily looking for an authentication. I don't need to verify any kind of biometric data, or even access the secure enclave at all, I just want to use it as another sensor on the phone.

In a similar way to how reachability works as of now on the iPhone, I'd want to just detect a touch on the sensor, not a button press.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at some of the jailbreak/Activator libraries? You probably wouldn't be able to include them in an iAS app, but it might give you some idea where to look.

Comment: I was hoping to put this up on the App Store, so not really. I'm sure that exists somewhere in the jailbreak community though haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API for this. I looked on `UIApplication` for a private API, and couldn't find one of those either.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I think it's a tool that could be used in lots of cool ways if it ever gets opened up to that point